# Plotting elliptical orbits

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy, orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to write a code that plots the elliptical paths of an object using the equation for the ellipse r=a(1-e^2)/(1+e*cos(theta)).  I'd also like this data to be put into an array for other use.

```
from numpy import *#Imports Python mathematical functions library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Imports plot library
from pylab import *

a = 5
e = 0.3
theta = 0
while theta <= 2*pi:
    r = (a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*cos(theta))
    print("r = ",r,"theta = ",theta)
    plt.polar(theta, r)
    theta += pi/180

plt.show()
```

The code spits out correct values for r and theta, but the plot is blank.  The polar plot window appears, but there is nothing plotted.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One quickly obvious flaw is theta being incremented by 180 degrees (in radians) - don't you want smaller steps, say 1 degree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not call `plt.polar` once for every point. Instead, call it once, with all the data as input:

```
import numpy as np #Imports Python mathematical functions library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Imports plot library
cos = np.cos
pi = np.pi

a = 5
e = 0.3
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi, 360)
r = (a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*cos(theta))
plt.polar(theta, r)

print(np.c_[r,theta])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

By the way, numpy can do the calculation as a two-liner, instead of using a while-loop:

```
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi, 360)   # 360 equally spaced values between 0 and 2*pi
r = (a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*cos(theta))
```

This defines `theta` and `r` as numpy arrays (rather than single values).

Comment: +1 same answer as I gave :) basically ... plus better info about linspace

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do `points.append([theta,r])` then  at the end `plt.polar(points)` ... that makes a kinda neat design too

```
from numpy import *#Imports Python mathematical functions library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Imports plot library
from pylab import *

a = 5
e = 0.3
theta = 0

points = []
while theta <= 2*pi:
    r = (a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*cos(theta))
    print("r = ",r,"theta = ",theta)
    points.append((theta, r))
    theta += pi/180
#plt.polar(points) #this is cool but probably not what you want
plt.polar(*zip(*points))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I was hoping this was Jupiter, but the eccentricity is *way* too big for that ...

Comment: Our answers are basically the same, but our plots are completely different! :) I'm a little perplexed about how to fix (yours or mine?), but since the theta's go from 0 to 2pi, shouldn't the plot make a single orbit?

Comment: Ah, our graphs would be the same if you use `plt.polar(*zip(*points))` so `plt.polar` receives two arguments instead of a single list. I'm not sure what `plt.polar` is doing when given a list of tuples...

Comment: lol oh I thought that was just the plot ... I thought it looked neato